# How fix binding element 'xyz' implicitly has an 'any' type?

Tags: typescript

Vscode show me:

```
Binding element 'id' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7031)
```

The problem concerned line 30:
const paths = posts.map(({ **id** }) => ({ params: { id: `${id}` } }));

Bellow code:

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { GetStaticProps } from "next";

export default function SSGPage({ post }: SSRPageProps) {
  console.log(post);
  return <main>{post.title}</main>;
}

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async ({ params }) => {
  if (!params?.id) {
    return {
      props: {},
      notFound: true,
    };
  }

  const res = await fetch(
    `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${params.id}`
  );
  const post = await res.json();
  return {
    props: { post },
  };
};

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const res = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
  const posts = await res.json();
  const paths = posts.map(({ id }) => ({ params: { id: `${id}` } }));
  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false,
  };
}

interface SSRPageProps {
  post: {
    userId: number;
    id: number;
    title: string;
    body: string;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
interface IPost {
 id: string;
}
....
const paths = posts.map(({ id }: IPost) => ({ params: { id: `${id}` } }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there is not type explicitly defined for `posts`, there is no type defined for the individual items in `posts`. `posts` takes up the type `any`.
And now you are trying to `destructure` properties from elements in the `posts` array. Obviously `TS` won't be aware of the type of property `id`. So `id` is also implicitly assigned `any`.

Looking at your usage you can do this:

```
 const paths = posts.map(({ id } : { id :string}) => ({ params: { id: `${id}` } }));
```

Now you inform `TS`, that `id` property is of `string` type